# How can I assign value to one of the columns based on the increasing value of date for those values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number, database-partitioning, data-partitioning

So I have a table which looks like this:

| StudentId | dateEnrolled |
| --- | --- |
| 23 | 03/01 |
| 23 | 05/01 |
| 23 | 07/05 |
| 23 | 08/11 |
| 23 | 03/01 |

I need to select these records such that I get the following records:

| StudentId | dateEnrolled |
| --- | --- |
| 23-1 | 03/01 |
| 23-2 | 05/01 |
| 23-3 | 07/05 |
| 23-4 | 08/11 |
| 23-1 | 03/01 |

There could be other dates after 08/11 in the records and if there are, student id would be 23-5 and so on

I tried to solve this using partition but I am not getting the desired result.

here's my code:

```
with temp as (
  select StudentId
  , dateEnrolled
  , row_number() over (
      partition by studentId 
      order by dateEnrolled
    ) as number
  from table1
)
select 
  concat(
    t.studentId, 
    '-', 
    (
      Select min(number)
      from temp
      group by studentId
    )
  )
, t.dateEnrolled
from temp t
```

My logic was to assign "-1" to the lowest date and then for for the next date 2 would be the minimum value for the number column so the id for that date would get "-2", but I ended up with a table that looks likes this:

| StudentId | dateEnrolled |
| --- | --- |
| 23-1 | 03/01 |
| 23-1 | 05/01 |
| 23-1 | 07/05 |
| 23-1 | 08/11 |
| 23-1 | 03/01 |

How can i fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `row_number()` how about `dense_rank()`

**Example**

```
Select StudentId = concat(StudentId,'-',dense_rank() over (partition by StudentId order by dateEnrolled) )
      ,dateEnrolled
 from YourTable
```

**Results**

```
StudentId   dateEnrolled
23-1        03/01
23-2        05/01
23-3        07/05
23-4        08/11
23-1        03/01
```